# Stranger things in Android class resolution

Tags: java, android, classloader, android-multidex, dexclassloader

I observe quite a few behaviors on Android (I am working on a multidex issue, so I use an emulator in 4.4.4) that leave me speechless about Android class loading:

On Android classes are **not** supposed to be resolved when being loaded by the class loader. But if I create a class:

```
public class M {
  public Foo m(String i) {
    switch (i) {
      case "0":
        return new Foo();
      case "1":
        return new Foo2();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

and debug my app, adding watches:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().findLoadedClass("Foo")
getClass().getClassLoader().findLoadedClass("Foo2")
```

Then I can see that loading `M` does load `Foo` and `Foo2`!

So the class **is** resolved.

Strangely enough, and that is almost a second question, but if I add `M extends Application`, then `M` is not resolved at all, even when instantiating it. `Foo` and `Foo2` only get loaded into the JVM when `m(X)` is called, (`Foo` is loaded when `X` is `"0"`, `Foo2` for `X="1"`).

Does anyone here have a rational explanations for these underlying questions:

- Why is `M` resolved, classes should not be resolved. Even instantiating `M` should not load `Foo` or `at least Foo2`.
- Why does a class extending `Application` behave differently?
- Are there other Android classes that behave in a different way?

Comment: linked to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219429

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behavior. Could you please share a sample app (perhaps as github repo) that demonstrates this issue?